# Adding idea module to openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I was trying to use idea encryption module in openssl. After installing openssl, while listing cipher commands, IDEA was absent there. The source does contain idea folder in crypto folder. While configuring the following message is displayed in terminal corresponding to configuring idea

```
making links in crypto/idea...
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/primal/openssl-1.0.0c/crypto/idea'
idea.h => ../../include/openssl/idea.h
ideatest.c => ../../test/ideatest.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/primal/openssl-1.0.0c/crypto/idea'
making links in crypto/bf..
```

While running make all command I got the following message

```
making all in crypto/idea...
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/primal/openssl-1.0.0c/crypto/idea'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/primal/openssl-1.0.0c/crypto/idea'
```

Any help on how to add idea support to openssl would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try following the suggestion in [this link](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/openssl.html), which is `MAKE_IDEA variable must be set in make.conf.`

Comment: Where do I look for make.conf file?

Comment: openssl builds with idea on my linux box with no specific configuration.  I think make.conf must be for older source

Comment: So how do I go about including idea module into openssl?